# Meteor Application - How might one implement orchestration/provisioning for multi-instance deployments?

Tags: javascript, shell, deployment, meteor

I have a meteor.js application that works well as a single instance deployment but now I want to setup the infrastructure to enable and automate the creation of more instances (1 for each client).

I intend to have a subdomain for each deployment that is reserved for a given client.

I image I have to have to:

1. Retrieve the desired subdomain for each client (through some sign-up site)
2. Bundle the application
3. Deploy an instance on a separate port with a separate DB for each
4. Setup a reverse proxy to forward the subdomain to the appropriate internal port
5. Setup something to monitor the processes and restart them if they crash or a reboot occurs
6. Automate re-bundling and deploying to all instances when the application code is updated and released

To the best of my understanding I think the appropriate tools for this job are in the orchestration family (Capistrano, Fabric, Func, Rundeck) but I don't understand what pieces they take care of and what pieces are/should be left to other tools.

A lot of my problems come from not knowing how to connect the steps and/or if they should be connected. Others come from not knowing what best practices are or where the design patterns around doing this sort of stuff can be learned.

For example:

- I know how to bundle the application on the command line but should that step be part of a shell script, or python script, or ruby.... same goes for step 2 in deployment (I know how to do it on the command line but not how to automate it)
- I imagine I could setup a reverse proxy but I don't know what reverse proxy tool out there can be dynamically modified or configured and what if any scripting language would be good for doing that dynamic configuration.
- I have no idea what considerations need to be made or should be made when updating/redeploying the apps.

Basically it seems like there are a number of tools out there and quite a few ways to do this stuff but very little guidance on what tools work well together or how to do it properly. I would be highly motivated to learn the necessary tools and languages if I didn't feeling like selecting a set of tools that work well together was effectively a dice roll.

Comment: I had a similar idea to you but ended up approaching it in a completely different way: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/8u2LVk8si_s. Are you sure it's completely necessary to actually run a separate app per client, or would a plugin that gives an app the appearance of segregation be good enough? It would also be much less resource-intensive.

Comment: I'm not sure you still need help on this - as you have another very similar Q on a different thread. That said, if all the apps share the same codebase, you shouldn't try to spawn a server instance per subdomain. Instead, the correct pattern is to use a * DNS, have nginx pool the request, then segregate subdomains by reading the headers in Meteor when the client connects. Scaling horizontally is done through cross-server communications (currently limited in Meteor until Galaxy lands), or share-nothing architectures.

Comment: yeah, I tried asking the question in two different ways as I learned more about the domain space. To me it seems lot easier to spawn a server instance per subdomain than it is to properly and securely segregate the application (Even if it doesn't scale as well). Having said that, I am clearly not experienced in this domain so I'll take your guy's word that this is the correct approach. If either of you would be interested in taking a look at the code I'd be happy to pay for the help of a consultant.

Comment: @StephanTual by the way, I tried to check out your blog/site http://www.stephantual.com/ and it appears to be down

Comment: Thank you @funkyeah, I've indeed taken that vps down in order to try new things with DDP clients haha... meteor is an addiction I'm afraid :D

Comment: @StephanTual well like I said, I'd be happy to help pay for your addiction if you don't mind getting your fix on my codebase (I have a little project myself and a few friends have been playing with in our spare time and I am working on taking it to the next level)

Comment: @funkyeah at this very moment I'm unfortunately not available for consulting, but try http://awwx.ws/ - I believe he might be. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

you could start with [meteor-up](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up) to make your servers run all the time (npm forever) and at startup.

[haproxy](http://www.haproxy.org/) has a [soft-reconfiguration](http://sysbible.org/2008/07/26/haproxy-hot-reconfiguration/) feature that allows to add and remove subdomains (or servers for a sub-domain) without restarting the service.

you should have everything you need to get going.